# pinch in pinch out working in core plot

Tags: iphone, charts, core-plot

Hi in core plot i m using following code

```
[graph.defaultPlotSpace setAllowsUserInteraction:YES];
[graph.defaultPlotSpace setDelegate:self];
```

to zoom the graph as well as plotted are i.e pie chart.

it's working fine for pinch in pinch out of graph axes but not zooming plotted are i.e pie chart.Looking for someone help.

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Core Plot pie chart zooming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117986/core-plot-pie-chart-zooming)